# Django print all permissions of a users in template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I am editing the user permissions in templates. And I want to display checked checkbox if user has permissions or unchecked if user has not specific permissions.

My View.py codes are as below.

```
def EditUserView(request,id=0):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    permission = Permission.objects.all()
    return render(request,'edituser.html',{"userdata":user,"permissions":permission})
```

And My templates code are as given below.

```html
 <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Permissions</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                {% for perm in permissions%}
                <tr>
                    <td id="perm">{{perm}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" onclick="ChangeUserPermissions(this,userid='{{userdata.id}}',permission='{{perm}}')"></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

My objectives of the code is only display checked checkbox if have permissions or unchecked if not have permissions

[image]

Comment: show your permission model. or is it standard django permission model?

Comment: standard django permission

Answer (score 1):

So you need to register custome tag for this it can be filter:

```
@register.filter
def has_perm(user, perm):
    return user.has_perm(perm)
```

then in template:

```
{% for perm in permissions%}

            <tr>
                <td>{{perm}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" onclick="ChangeUserPermissions(this,userid='{{userdata.id}}',permission='{{perm}}')"
                {% if user|has_perm:perm %} selected {% endif %}>
                 </td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

those ids on td tags wont be uniqe